# Simple-file-upload addon returns no file on submit - django

Tags: python, html, django-views, django-forms

I've been trying to add a heroku addon on my deploy. I have tried configuring the simple-file-upload but it still doesn't give the desired result.
It returns (Hidden field File) This field is required.
Here are my attempts.

views.py

```
class AddDownloadView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Download
    form_class = AddDownloadsForm
    template_name = 'add_file.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('all_downloads')
```

models.py

```
class Download(models.Model):
    File = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
    File_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk','File_Name')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.File_Name
```

forms.py

```
class AddDownloadsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Download
        fields = ("File",'File_Name')

    
        widgets = {
            "File":forms.FileInput(attrs={"class":'simple-file-upload','type':'hidden'}),
            "File_Name":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),}
```

add_file.html < form for adding the file uploads >

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.media }}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

form for displaying the uploads

```
<div style="min-height:350px;columns:200px 2;overflow-y:scroll;" class="container alert alert- 
default" role="alert">
{% for item in file %}
    {% if item.File_Name %}
     --><a href=" {{ item.File.url }}">  {{ item.File_Name }}</a><br>
     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            ==> <a href="{% url 'update_file' item.id %}" style="color:grey">Edit</a> || 
            <a href="{% url 'delete_file' item.id %}" style="color:red">Delete</a><hr>
         {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% empty %}<br><br>
    <h6><i>No files to download yet</i></h6><br><br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I've struglled through same problems but have not come up with a solution, please help.

Comment: Can you share the rendered HTML? My first guess is that this line ` "File":forms.FileInput(attrs={"class":'simple-file-upload','type':'hidden'}),` is returning a file field. The value is returned as a string, not a file. So you want HTML that returns a hidden field.

Comment: @leenyburger, Rendered HTML? I don't get you, please.

Comment: If you run your local server, and look at the html in the developer tools for the form - what does it look like?